# Сломанная кодировка Arch Linux в выводе в консоли

Tags: кодировка, archlinux

У меня Arch Linux Sway. Могу вводить русские буквы, но консоль не отображает русские буквы.

Вывод из консоли

```sh
    ls -a
 .             Aquarium
 ..           ''$'\320\235\320\276\320\262\320\260\321\217'' '$'\320\277\320\260\320\277\320\272\320\260'
 .Trash-1000  ''$'\320\276\320\273\320\265'
 AntiSpy      ''$'\321\202\321\200\320\260\321\204\320\260\321\200\320\265\321\202\321\213'
```

Comment: Невнимательно следовали [руководству по установке](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)#%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) и забыли прописать LANG в настройках?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло